# How to acquire the position of QLabel and separate it into x- and y-coordinate variables in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am creating a GUI to drag and drop 5 labels. I want to calculate the distance between any of the two labels by using their `x-` and `y-coordinate` of their positions.

I know what with `label1.pos()` method we can get the position of each label. For example, this is what we may acquire:

```
PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(180, 140)
```

Hence I would like to access the `x-` and `y-coordinate` directly in the codes, and use Pythagorean theorem to calculate the distance between them. Do anyone know how to do this?

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you just need to calculate the distance between two points, you can use `QLine(p1, p2).length()`.

Comment: Hi Romha, thanks for your reply. I see. So I could get the distance with QLine(label1.pos(), label2.pos()).length(). Now that I have learned another alternative!

Comment: One small correction here: QLine has no attribute length(). QLineF instead works fine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for that :

```
label1.x()
label1.y()
```

?

Comment: Hi Nqsir, thank you for your reply. Yea exactly! With .x() and .y() I get the coordinate directly. Perfect!